# Sperner's Lemma in infinite-dimensional spaces?

Tags: combinatorics, vector-spaces

I've been looking at Sperner's Lemma for a little while and have managed to come to grips with some of the combinatorial proofs. Some descriptions I have encountered claim to prove it for "simplices" and some for "$n$-simplices", and there didn't seem to be any particularly large differences between the proofs. On the other hand, it seems nontrivial to formulate Sperner's Lemma in infinite dimensions.

It doesn't seem like there should be anything preventing us from defining simplices in arbitrary real infinite-dimensional topological vector spaces (RIDTVSs). But having little experience with them, I don't know how Sperner's Lemma would work there. In particular I know that closed balls in RIDTVSs are not compact, which could reasonably be hiding in the background of the combinatorial proofs. It certainly plays a role in the equivalent Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem.

Does anyone know of a formulation of Sperner's Lemma in RIDTVSs, or at least have a reference to an analytic proof in finite dimensions that might be illuminating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just consider $\mathbb R^\infty $, the set of all infinite sequences of real numbers with almost all entries equal to $0$. Then the infinite dimensional simplex is most naturally defined to be the closure of the convex hall of all the standard basis vectors (i.e., all zeros with only one $1$). Things basically work. See [this artilce](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610707).

Comment: That article does not require almost all entries to be zero. Thank you for linking it; it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't read the paper in any detail, I believe that Theorem 6.1 from [this article](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/119611/CommentatMathUnivCarolRetro_47-2006-3_13.pdf) like a theorem I was hoping for:

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $\phi:[n]^\omega\to\{0,1\}^\omega$. Then there is $\sigma\in [n]^\omega$ such that $\phi(K_\sigma)$ is infinite.

It is formulated on a cube instead of a simplex, and appears to be only able to handle countable dimensions, but it's a start.